# Can't get my refresh rate right

Tags: nvidia, xorg, resolution

After reading tons and tons of manuals and forums about the problem I need to ask myself, because I can't figure out what's wrong.

In my new PC there's a GTX 660 connected to LG Flatron L1730S using D-SUB / DVI connetor. This monitor is able to work at 1280x1024 with 75 Hz refresh rate and I'm not able to set it anyhow.

I can create a new mode in xrandr but I can't connect it with DVI-I-0 output to which my monitor is connected.

After

```
xrandr --addmode DVI-I-0 1280x1024_75.00
```

I get this:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
Serial number of failed request:  39
Current serial number in output stream:  40
```

It's been two days now, and at 60 Hz I get my screen is flickering.

Please, help me get it right.

PS. I use nV proprietary 331.113

Comment: Are you using a converter or a connector?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got what the problem really was - it was related with the connector I used. There's no way to fix it another than changing connector to converter as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: That's why I asked you this 5 months ago... (see above)